# How to silence OpenCV "Camera dropped frame"

Tags: opencv

Under Mac OS X, opencv complains that the camera drops frames and writes the following messages: "Camera dropped frame!".

Anybody know how to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code it seems to be written to cout and not just in debug.

Easiest way (if you are on Windows) is to build your app as system=win rather than console so there is no output.

Or you could fix the code and recompile (and submit a patch) !

Comment: There was a patch submitted to the OpenCV 2.4 branch to print these messages to standard error instead of standard output, but it doesn't seem as though it was ever merged into any release: http://code.opencv.org/issues/980

Comment: The relevant current line in the OpenCV 2.4 branch is:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/highgui/src/cap_qtkit.mm#L561

Comment: The relevant current line in the OpenCV 3.1.0 release is:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_qtkit.mm#L558